# Foreign Key constraints error

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I wrote down a primary and foreign key into the code but it displays an error:

> Foreign key constraints is incorrectly formed

Could anyone help me with my issue?

This is what I wrote:

```
USE sgschool; 
CREATE TABLE StudentSubject(studentno INT(5) NOT NULL,
  subjectID INT(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT schSubjectIDFK FOREIGN KEY(SubjectID) REFERENCES Subjects (subjectID), 
  CONSTRAINT schStudentNoFK FOREIGN KEY(studentNo) REFERENCES student(StudentID),
  PRIMARY KEY(studentNo,subjectID));
```

Comment: Your constraints are incorrectly formed. Try the MySQL documentation for CREATE TABLE. Google should be able to find it; search for *MySQL x.x documentation*, replacing *x.x* with the MySQL version you're using.

Comment: I'm using the updated version of it.

Comment: MySQL documentation is updated. Find the version that is for the MySQL version you're using. I even provided the search phrase for you. What more do you want? Someone to stop by your desk to read it to you?

Comment: Read & act on [mcve]. Part of finding minimal code showing the problem is finding a maximal subset of that that doesn't show the problem. Look at the difference.

Answer (score 0):

When including the constraint as part of the table creation, you do not need to include the name of the constrained column, because the constraint is part of the column definition.

Try this:

```
    studentno INT (5) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT schStudentNoFK FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES student(StudentID),
    subjectID INT (10) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT schSubjectIDFK FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Subjects(subjectID),
```

If you are adding the constraint after the table is created, then you need to tell SQL to which column you are adding the constraint, but again, that is not necessary when you include the constraint with the table definition.

On a side note, try to be more consistent with your casing and pluralization.  You have student(StudentID) and Subjects(subjectID).  Either making them all singular or make them all plural; make them all lower case, UPPER CASE or PascalCase, but don't intermix them within the same solution.  Those little nuances may cause you grief later.